Error de compilación al crear formularios con useForm en bucle
Tengo el siguiente error de compilación:
Failed to compile.

./src/app/[locale]/(portfoil)/admin/project-translations/[id]/ui/tabs-translations.tsx
24:37  Error: React Hook "useForm" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
   Linting and checking validity of types  .

El causante del problema está siendo este trozo de mi código:
    const forms: { [key: string]: UseFormReturn<ProjectTranslation> } = {};
    projectTranslations.forEach(translation => {
        forms[translation.locale] = useForm<ProjectTranslation>({
            defaultValues: {
                file: translation?.file,
                shortDescription: translation?.shortDescription,
                description: translation?.description,
            }
        });
    });

Es en una aplicación de nextjs en el que creo un formulario distinto por cada lenguaje de traducción disponible.
¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

EDIT
Aquí dejo el código completo del componente:
'use client'

import { ProjectTranslation, updateProjectDescription, updateProjectDocumentation, updateProjectShortDescription } from '@/actions';
import { Avatar, Tab, Tabs, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext';
import TabPanel from '@mui/lab/TabPanel';
import { UseFormReturn, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

interface Props {
    projectId: string;
    projectTranslations: ProjectTranslation[];
}

const TabsTranslations = ({ projectTranslations, projectId }: Props) => {

    const [currentLocale, setCurrentLocale] = useState<string>(projectTranslations[0].locale);
    const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
        setCurrentLocale(newValue);
    };

    const forms: { [key: string]: UseFormReturn<ProjectTranslation> } = {};
    projectTranslations.forEach(translation => {
        forms[translation.locale] = useForm<ProjectTranslation>({
            defaultValues: {
                file: translation?.file,
                shortDescription: translation?.shortDescription,
                description: translation?.description,
            }
        });
    });

    const handleSubmitForm = (locale: string) => {
        return async (data: ProjectTranslation) => {

            const { description, file, shortDescription } = data;

            if (description) {
                await updateProjectDescription(projectId, description, locale);
            }

            if (shortDescription) {
                await updateProjectShortDescription(projectId, shortDescription, locale);
            }

            if (file) {
                await updateProjectDocumentation(projectId, file, locale);
            }
        };
    };

    return (
        <TabContext value={currentLocale}>
            <Tabs value={currentLocale} onChange={handleChange} variant="fullWidth">
                {
                    projectTranslations.map((item, index) => (
                        <Tab key={index} value={item.locale}
                            icon={<Avatar alt="test avatar" variant="square" src={`/imgs/${item.locale}.flag.svg`} />}
                        />

                    ))
                }
            </Tabs>
            {projectTranslations.map((item, index) => (
                <TabPanel key={index} value={item.locale}>
                    <form
                        className='flex flex-col gap-4'
                        onSubmit={forms[item.locale].handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm(item.locale))}
                    >
                        <div className='flex flex-col mb-2'>
                            <span>Documentación</span>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className='p-2 border rounded-md bg-gray-200'
                                {...forms[item.locale].register('file', { required: false })}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='flex flex-col mb-2'>
                            <span>Resumen</span>
                            <textarea
                                rows={2}
                                className='p-2 border rounded-md bg-gray-200'
                                {...forms[item.locale].register('shortDescription', { required: false })}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='flex flex-col mb-2'>
                            <span>Descripción</span>
                            <textarea
                                rows={5}
                                className='p-2 border rounded-md bg-gray-200'
                                {...forms[item.locale].register('description', { required: false })}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" className='p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md'>
                            Guardar
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </TabPanel>
            ))}


        </TabContext>
    )
}

export default TabsTranslations


Bueno el error es claro, no se puede usar un hook en un scope de callback, Y ¿Como estas tratando de consumir esto más adelante forms[translation.locale]? Imagino que estas creando un componente por lenguaje y pasas forms[translation.locale] como props? sería bueno que agregaras esa pieza de código también

Cuando llegue a casa añadiré todo el componente, pero si, algo así hago

Comparto un ejemplo mínimo, pero funciona sin problemas, ya solo es cuestion de adaptarlo a tu ejemplo.
El componente TabsTranslations se puede componer usando un patron conocido como bajar el estado a un componente y crear tu propio componente MyForm, este componente se puede iterar con la estructura projectTranslations:
return (
    <>
      //codigo...
      {projectTranslations.map((item, index) => (
        <MyForm item={item} key={index} />
      ))}
      //mas codigo...
    </>
  );

Luego, dentro de ese componente MyForm se usa el custom hook useForm(se baja el estado) para obtener las propiedades por elemento y devolver los forms independientes por cada iteración de projectTranslations, con esto evitas el error:

Error: React Hook "useForm" cannot be called inside a callback

"use client";
import useForm from "../hooks/useForm";

export default function MyForm({ item }: { item: any }) {
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      file: item.file,
      shortDescription: item.shortDescription,
      description: item.description,
    },
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
      <button type="submit">Submit {item.locale}</button>
    </form>
  );
}

Versión dummy de useForm usado para las pruebas:
export default function useForm({ defaultValues }: { defaultValues: any }) {
  console.log("re-render: useMyHook");
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit", defaultValues);
  };
  return { handleSubmit };
}

Te sugiero implementar este ejemplo mínimo por separado para que puedas observar el cambio en la composición y luego ya puedas adaptar a tu caso de uso.

Perfecto muchas gracias!! No se me había ocurrido hacerlo con un componente separado, me obcequé
